# How to run Jquery function on modal popup button click

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal popup that has a save button on it when clicked this should trigger a jQuery function
here is my button code

```
<button id="btnSave" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="SaveChanges">Save Changes</button>
```

Why the function is not fired when the button is clicked

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you need to invoke your function with parenthesis. Otherwise, you just pass the function definition to the `onclick` event.

```js
function SaveChanges() {
  console.log('SaveChanges runs!');
}
```

```html
<button id="btnSave" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="SaveChanges()">Save Changes</button>
```

BTW, in any case, I discourage you from using inline event handlers to stick with [unobtrusive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) solution. Instead of that, you may need to use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) like this:

```js
function SaveChanges() {
  console.log('SaveChanges runs!');
}

const btn = document.getElementById('btnSave');
btn.addEventListener('click', SaveChanges);
```

```html
<button id="btnSave" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Save Changes</button>
```

Or by jQuery itself you can do that like this:

```js
$('#btnSave').click(function() {
  console.log('SaveChanges runs!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnSave" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Save Changes</button>
```

Comment: Why it would now work with id here is the script $(document).ready(function(){ $('#btnsave').on('click', function(){alert ("you clicked me"})

Comment: I first try it with the id, the function did not get fired then I tried with the class it did not work either until you show me my missing () error. I wonder why it did not work when i used the id of the button. I posted the script function in the previous comment

Comment: @Schleid First of all, your script got some issue with opening and closing parenthesis, but if we exclude it, you use `btnsave` in your listeners then `btnSave` in your button element which are not equal, because first one is all in lowercase and the second one is in camel case *(`'btnsave' !== 'btnSave'`)*. Also if the answer works for you please don't forget to upvote it also. 

Comment: I wrote the button name correctly both in the button id an the function sorry for the case problem while writing the post.

Comment: I just post a more important issue, please check it out and help me thanks in advance